# Best small pet for a fairly small space in a bedroom

Tags: adoption

Basically, I've been thinking of buying myself a small pet to put in my room. The problem is, i have an very tiny room, and the only real place i can put it is in a corner next to my wardrobe and the wall, which is a gap of about 60cm or 23 inches (so less than that to move the cage.)

I thought of buying a dwarf hamster, since there small and should fit that space. The problem being there nocturnal and I'm worried they'll keep me up at night (although i can be a very sound sleeper.)

What other small pets would be good for that space? Reptiles are mostly out of the questions since i dont want crickets and insects in my room, and fish seem a bit too boring for me.

Comment: Can the pet have access to your room, or must they stay in the cage?  Are there other pets or children under 6 years old in the house?  What are the temperature ranges in the home (do you have heat & air conditioning)?  How many years are you prepared for the pet to live?

Comment: see http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/q/1930/1313

Comment: Related question [What small pets should I consider for a preteen with limited space?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6694)

Answer (score 1):

in a space that small, you will probably not want any pets at all. Yes, we all love pets, but if you do you also have to realise when you can't provide them with a suitable environment to live in.
And being crammed between a cabinet and a wall isn't the right place for a pet, it's too claustrophobic.

If you insist, the small rodents are probably your best bet indeed. But yes, many are nocturnal which means they're not that great company during the day. But (from when my sister had hamsters years and years ago) they're not really noisy (unless you give them a hamsterwheel that squeaks).
I'd myself be more concerned about smell, dust, and other things that you just don't notice as much in a larger space. A rodent cage can smell rather strongly close up, even if you clean it thoroughly several times a week, and in a room that small the smell may be overpowering.